# Binaries size not decreasing after artifact deletion in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, binaries, jfrog-container-registry

I have deleted all the artifacts from my instance of Artifactory cloud, and I have deleted all the repositories, but the Binaries size is still showing as 1.5GB.

[image]

How to resolve this issue?

I am not seeing a maintenance option in JFrog. I am an individual user and I am the admin for this account.

Answer (score 1):

Artifacts in Artifactory are not removed immediately. There is a default trash can that stores your artifacts for 2 weeks by default, before deleting them forever.

The trash can settings can be accessed only by admin, therefore as a non-admin user, you can wait ~2 weeks or ask your Artifactory admin to empty the trash can.

To empty the trash can as admin, go to `Administration | Artifactory | General | Settings` and then click on the "Empty Trash Can"

For more information see:

- [Trash Can Settings](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+Artifactory#ConfiguringArtifactory-TrashCanSettings)
- [How can I completely remove artifacts from Artifactory?](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-can-i-completely-remove-artifacts-from-artifactory/)
- [How to delete artifact from Trash can in Jfrog Artifactory?](https://manastri.blogspot.com/2020/07/how-to-delete-trash-can-in-jfrog.html)

Comment: I tried empty trash can option. Artifacts are deleting but Binary size is not reducing.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late, but let me share this info so it may be helpful to others.

There are two scenarios

1. You can check whether the Trash is cleaned up or not, if not the usual retention period is 14 days, meaning once you delete any artifact it will come to Trash (if Trash facility is enabled). It will be in trash for 14 days after this period automatically Trash will be cleaned up.
2. When we delete any artifact in UI or by using Jfrog API it will not delete the actual binary of that artifact, instead it will delete the checksum of that binary.
   In above case you can see in the screenshot Binary size is 1.53 GB and the artifact size is 8.06 MB which should not the case.

Artifact size will always be higher than Binary size.

But the reason for the above issue is - artifactoy will store binaries in checksum based storage.

So when we delete the artifact it will delete the checksum alone, not the actual binary.

Then this actual binaries will be deleted by GC run by artifactory for every 4 hours by default(this will be triggered by cront exp, we can run this manually by using API as well).

While running the GC jfrog will check is there any binaries without any checksum reference, then it will be deleted during GC run.

Please refer below links for detailed info.

[https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-does-removing-deleting-old-artifacts-is-not-affecting-the-artifactory-disk-space-usage/#:~:text=The%20above%20behavior,any%20other%20repository](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-does-removing-deleting-old-artifacts-is-not-affecting-the-artifactory-disk-space-usage/#:%7E:text=The%20above%20behavior,any%20other%20repository).